# How to create a table with "nested" rows / column values in R?

Tags: r

I'm not sure if "nested" is the right word. I have a data frame with multiple ID variables including "n" and "Method"  then three variables that are numeric. For each value of n, there are 2 values for Method (prime or samp).

- n   Method   t1    t5   gaussian
- 100  prime .....................
- 100  samp  .....................
- 200  prime   ...................
- 200  samp ......................
- etc.............................

And I need to display it in a table so that "n" is only shown once for the 2 different methods. It should look like the picture linked as a shell table.

I can get the correct format for n and method using tabular() but then I am displaying the counts for gaussian, t1 and t5, which are all 1, when really I want to display the actual values.

```
tabular(data=r, n*Method ~ Format(digits=4)*(t1 + t5 + gaussian))
```

[image]
...

Answer (score 1):

I assume the data frame you have is as follows:

```r
dput(mydf)
structure(list(n = c("100", "100", "200", "200"), Method = c("prime", 
"samp", "prime", "samp"), t1 = c("", "", "", ""), t5 = c("", 
"", "", ""), gaussian = c("", "", "", "")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
#   n Method t1 t5 gaussian
# 1 100  prime               
# 2 100   samp               
# 3 200  prime               
# 4 200   samp
```

So what you can do is:

```r
mydf$n[duplicated(mydf$n)] <- " "
#   n Method t1 t5 gaussian
# 1 100  prime               
# 2       samp               
# 3 200  prime               
# 4       samp
```

This should give you the output format you desire.